# Как сделать проброс портов для MySQL?

Tags: mysql, порты, portforwarding

Есть сервер(мой рабочий ПК) с `MySQL`. Не могу подключиться к нему по внешнему `ip`. Подсказали что надо сделать проброс портов, но как это сделать?

Роутер: Keenetic Viva

ОС: Windows 10

Version MySQL: 8.0.11

Comment: Открыть в настройках роутера переадресацию да добавить правило проброса TCP-порта 3306

Comment: @andreymalm, в теории всё хорошо, а на деле не пашет((( Выдаёт так: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip' (115)`

Comment: Посмотрите каким пользователем хотите войти. У юзеров `user@localhost` и `user@%` разные разрешения.

Comment: @AlexeGlebe, создал пользователя с %. Значит у меня `user@%` и я должен подключаться хоть с какого ip

Comment: По внешнему IP вы хотите войти из локальной сети или из внешней?

Comment: `username@'%' : подключаться может с любого компьютера, кроме localhost`

Источник: https://intellect.icu/dostup-k-mysql-iz-seti-11105

Comment: Пункт номер раз: вы убедились что у вас действительно есть белый IP у *вашего роутера*?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, белый ip я не получал, но чисто теоретически вроде я могу обратиться к своему ПК... По крайней мере, читал что это вполне возможно. Правда, было сказано что при перезапуске ПК/роутера он постоянно будет меняться

Comment: @AlexGlebe, значит всё делаю правильно, т.к. я подключаюсь со своего ноута и мне надо чтобы другие люди тоже могли подключиться к БД

Comment: но чисто теоретически вроде я могу обратиться к своему ПК — через мировой эфир что ли?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, честно, я не силён в этом, потому и обратился за помощью сюда. Читал на каком-то сайте что это возможно, но было это месяца 4 назад и ссылку я не сохранил(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался! Неправильно делал переадресацию. НЕ заметил пункт на подключение с Ethernet, а по-умолчанию стоит локалка. Всё теперь работает) Всем спасибо!

Comment: @strawdog, как раз является ответом) Просто у Keenetic в новой версии есть выбор откуда принимать подключения,  данный пункт я НЕ заметил => только в этом и была ошибка => данное сообщение является ответом на вопрос и говорит чтобы внимательнее смотрели на все пункты)